# Fix deleted USB Driver on the keyboard ( after reset factory ) and The keyboard is not recognized by the computer

Tags: java, keyboard, usb, driver, custom-keyboard

**3 days ago** I bought a mechanical keyboard that had several different programs that worked with them
I decided to install programs for it so that I can make better use of the keyboard (even because of RGBs, Macros, etc.)
In the .zip file that I downloaded, there was a program that I opened by mistake, and it returns the keyboard to its factory state , and evel deleted that firmware of keyboard , and USB driver on it too
After that, my keyboard was not connected to the computer at all, because its USB was not recognized by the computer at all (I feel that it has a driver that has been deleted).
Please tell me how I can reinstall its USB driver so that I can install frimware on it after connected to PC
Ty alot for your kindness helps
( and please dont say guys refound it to Company or etc.
I want to fix it on my Own and yours help

I checked it in Device Manager , and around 2 minute after i connected keyboard to PC , that shows me : Unkown USB Device (Device Information error)